# My program to count the number of vowels in a string always outputs 0 or 1

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a beginner learning C.

I'm trying to write a simple program to calculate the number of vowels in a user-entered string. I'm using a do-while loop to iterate through string. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[10], x=0, v=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("ENTER A STRING: ");
    gets(a);
    do {
        if(a[x]=='a' || a[x]=='e' || a[x]=='i' || a[x]=='o' || a[x]=='u')
            v++;
        x++;
    } while(a[x] != '\0');
    printf("\nTHERE ARE %d VOWELS IN THE STRING.",v);
    getch();
}
```

For some reason, the output is either turns out as 1 or 0, regardless of how many vowels are entered.

Here is the output:

```
ENTER A STRING: aeiou

THERE ARE 1 VOWELS IN THE STRING.
```

I'm not able to prick out the mistake.

Comment: Start indenting your code. And please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: (1) Turn on all compiler warnings. (2) This program is small enough that you can just step through it line by line in a debugger to see where it doesn't do what was expected.

Comment: You should get a compiler warning that tells you exactly what the problem is....

Comment: Upvoted: thank you for salvaging this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've declared `a` as an `int` array (rather than a `char` array) and that's why you get the problem.

If you're interested in why you're always seeing `0` or `1`, consider an `int` of four bytes and you read in a string `aeiou` (into what `gets` assumes is an array of characters):

```
  a[0]   a[1]
| aeio | u    |
```

As you can see, all but the final `int` *must* be composed of four bytes so will never be equal to a single-byte vowel character (unless three of them were NUL characters but that's unlikely from user input). The final one will either be a single character which will give you `1` if it's a vowel (`0` otherwise), or a 2/3/4-character `int` which again could not be a vowel.

Declare `a` as `char a[10]`, this will allow you to store the string and access its individual character elements.

Answer (score 4):

Using `int[]` to model an array of characters is not going to end well. (What's *possibly* happening is that `a[1]` is always zero.)

Use `char a[10]` instead, to get you started at least. (Although this will be only good for 9 characters plus the nul-terminator).

So you don't overrun your character buffer, consider using

`fgets(str, 10, stdin);` instead. This will read in, at most, 9 characters.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, use char array to store characters. Also, indent your code so you can read it more clearly. Working version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=0,v=0;
    char a[10];
    printf("ENTER A STRING: ");
    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("%s\n", a);
    do
    {
        if((a[x]=='a')||(a[x]=='e')||(a[x]=='i')||(a[x]=='o')||(a[x]=='u'))
            v++;
        x++;
    }
    while(a[x]!='\0');
    printf("\nTHERE ARE %d VOWELS IN THE STRING.",v);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I do really wish that all those Indian universities would just retire TurboC (see `conio` and `getch`) and just start using one of the free *modern* ones, it's so far out of date it's not doing students *any* favours.

Comment: The compilers might be free, but the machines they might need to run them are not.